# Flutter Web showing Blank white screen for few seconds then showing Output

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I Developed Basic Flutter Website, There is no Errors and Flutter Doctor also all-Right

But When I hosted my website on Server, It's showing few seconds(8s) Blank white Screen then Showing Real Output

and also I tried to analyze my website with GTMETRIX but not getting Result

```
Analysis Error
Lighthouse Error: Failed to find the Largest Contentful Paint
```

Pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  charts_flutter: ^0.11.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  data_table_2: ^2.1.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  get: ^4.3.8
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.282], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: That's the splash screen. You can implement your own splash screen. See the package `flutter_native_splash`.  [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash]. Here's a quote from that page: "When your app is opened, there is a brief time while the native app loads Flutter. By default, during this time, the native app displays a white splash screen."

Comment: Thanks @RoslanAmir, I got reason, 
Can you tell me how to remove that splash screen? I don't need it

Comment: You should read this article https://medium.com/flutter-community/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-web-7930e5e44bd

Comment: @sunakshi sinha I think there is no way to remove it. That time is needed by Flutter while "booting up." All we can do is show our own splash screen instead of the empty white screen. But the 8 seconds you got is a bit excessive.